# Return and combine all cell values from a row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet and would like to return all cell values from a specific row into one cell. For example return all cell values containing the text "TBB" from row 3 without displaying the search word (TBB) and adding certain characters and a line break between each result to separate them. So the result in the cell would look like the following, where the original values are: TBB Result1, TBB Result2, TBB Result3

Result1

Result2

Result3

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to find the cells in row 3 than begin with TBB:

```
filter(A3:3, regexmatch(A3:3, "^TBB"))
```

Second step, remove TBB and whatever whitespace follows it:

```
arrayformula(regexreplace([previous formula], "^TBB\s*", ""))
```

Third step, join the results, separating them by new lines `char(10)`.

```
join(char(10), [previous formula])
```

All of this together:

```
=join(char(10), arrayformula(regexreplace(filter(A3:3, regexmatch(A3:3, "^TBB")), "^TBB\s*", "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this formula in A3:

```
=transpose(split(substitute(A1,"TBB",""),","))
```

[image: SO47539910 first example]

or maybe in B3:

```
=substitute(substitute(A1,"TBB",""),",",Char(10))
```

[image: SO47539910 second example]